# Stylelint formats .tsx files to .css

Tags: reactjs, eslint, styled-components, stylelint

Stylelint seems to format my `.tsx` files to `.css` in strange way.
Lets assume that this is my component:

```js
const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  &&& {
    padding: 0;
  }
`;
```

when I save it, stylelint formats it to something like it:

```css
.selector27 {
  &&& {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

What's wrong?

This is my `.stylelinrc.json` file:

```json
{
  "processors": [
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss", 
    "stylelint-config-styled-components"
  ],
  "customSyntax": "postcss-scss",
  "rules": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stylelint processors are incompatible with autofix.

You should just use an appropriate custom system instead.

For example:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss", 
    "stylelint-config-styled-components"
  ],
  "customSyntax": "@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js",
  "rules": {}
}
```